# Java-scripts stop working once using HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https

Is there is any reason for Javascripts stop working under HTTPS but under HTTP all working fine. paths to files are:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

I have no other paths files attached.

I am using .htaccess to rewrite for HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.test-website.com
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Have you checked in browser's debugger console for the actual error. There should be error. Let us know that error.

Comment: It seems to be related with server side configuration related with script execution rights.   :(

Comment: I am running checks on the server, cheers